# How to find the value of kernel.shmmax from C code

Tags: c, ubuntu, centos, shared-memory, sysctl

I want to get the value of kernel.shmmax in C code (which I query on centos5.0, centos6.0 and ubuntu10.04 using the shell command "$ sysctl -q kernel.shmmax").

I used the following code to find it:

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>

const int SHM_ERROR=1;

main(){
    int name[] = {KERN_SHMMAX};
    int namelen = 1;
    int oldval[1];
    size_t oldlen = sizeof(oldval);
    int rv = sysctl(name, namelen, (void*) oldval, &oldlen, NULL, 0);
    if (rv!=0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "while quering for shared memory size, sysctl returned error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return SHM_ERROR;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

After running the code above I get the following error:

while quering for shared memory size, sysctl returned error: Not a directory

I am clueless about why I am getting this error. I googled for it and found there is some issue with the paths into which library tries to look into.

I tried running the above code with GDB but the code doesn't steps into the function sysctl, otherwise I could have provided you more information.

Data point:
I am easily able to set and get kernel.shmmax from command line on all the operating systems mentioned using the following commands:

$ sysctl -q kernel.shmmax

$ sysctl -w kernel.shmmax=1000000000

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be calling `sysctl` from userspace code.  From the `man` page:

> Glibc does not provide a wrapper for this system call; call it using
>   syscall(2).
>
> Or rather... don't call it: use of this system call has long been
>   discouraged, and it is so unloved that **it is likely to disappear in a
>   future kernel version**.  Remove it from your programs now; use the
>   /proc/sys interface instead.

So give this a shot instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>                                                                                                                  

#define SHMMAX_SYS_FILE "/proc/sys/kernel/shmmax"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int shmmax;
    FILE *f = fopen(SHMMAX_SYS_FILE, "r");

    if (!f) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file: `%s'\n", SHMMAX_SYS_FILE);
        return 1;
    }

    if (fscanf(f, "%u", &shmmax) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read shmmax from file: `%s'\n", SHMMAX_SYS_FILE);
        fclose(f);
        return 1;
    }

    fclose(f);

    printf("shmmax: %u\n", shmmax);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was reluctant to use this method since I was afraid that this may have more chances to break across operating systems since assuming location of a file to be standard across platforms looked to be a big assumption. Is the path to shmmax file i.e. /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax a standard across various operating systems? I have checked on ubuntu and centos and it is matching but worried for other operating systems.

Comment: It's specific to Linux, but so is the call to `sysctl`.  It should work on all distributions of Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I install strace and see that sysctl looks at /proc/sys/kernel/shmmax with open() call instead of _sysctl() call or syscall() call.